# Hide div when clicked anywhere but another div w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following function that hide s a certain div when I click anywhere on a page:

```
$("html").click(function() {
    $(".myDiv1").addClass("hidden");
});
```

I would like to add an exception to this function. If a click is within another div, ignore this hiding... The only way for me to select the second function is to pick a distinct element withing it:

```
$(".nyOtherDiv").parent()
```

How do I combine these? Or shall I just add it as a separate function below to overwrite the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to see what element was clicked on. If it was that div that you want to exclude then don't add the class else add the class.

```
var exclude_div = $(".nyOtherDiv").parent();  
$(document).click(function(e){
   if( !exclude_div.is( e.target ) )  // if target div is not the one you want to exclude then add the class hidden
        $(".myDiv1").addClass("hidden");  

});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJfHy/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).not('div').click(function() { 
    //everywhere in the document that is NOT a div
    $(".myDiv1").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: No, I need to be precise to the exact one I mentioned. I have quite a few divs on the page ;)

Comment: @santa so change the selector in the `not`

Comment: Oh I see... Like this, i suppose: $(document).not($(".nyOtherDiv").parent()
).click(function() { Thanks.

Comment: That's not going to work. The even handler is not attached to each of the elements in the page, it's attached to the `document`, so the `.not()` is pointless.